# I can access fatimatestpro.pythonanywhere.com but not fatimatestpro.pythonanywhere.com/help/

Tags: python, django

I am working on PythonAnywhere and made my first project. I am trying to access many views (HTML pages) from my views.py. Here is my project tree:

emailpro
--emailpro
----url.py
--emailapp
----urls.py
----views.py
--templates
----emailapp
------index.html
------help.html

Code inside my emailpro>emailpro>urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
#from emailapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('', include('emailapp.urls')),
]
```

Code inside my emailpro>emailapp>urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from emailapp import views

urlpatterns=[

    url('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^help/$',  views.help, name='help'),

]
```

Code inside my emailpro>emailapp>views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    my_dict={'insert_me': "Hi I am index coming from views.py"}
    return render(request, 'emailapp/index.html', context=my_dict)

def help(request):
    help_dict={'help_insert': "HELP PAGE"}
    return render(request, 'emailapp/help.html', context=help_dict)
```

My emailpro>templates>emailapp>index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Index page</h1>
    {{ insert_me }}

  </body>
</html>
```

Code inside my emailpro>templates>emailapp>help.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Help </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is my Help HTML</h1>
    {{ help_insert }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run my site and access http://fatimatestpro.pythonanywhere.com/, it shows me my index.html page which means it is going inside my emailpro>emailapp>urls.py to get its view from views.py but when I try to access http://fatimatestpro.pythonanywhere.com/help/, it shows the same page as index.html.
Please help me to send it to different view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your index url is matching before it reaches the help url.

try:

```
urlpatterns=[

    url(r'^help/$',  views.help, name='help'),
    url('/', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. It worked. The answer was logical. I was thinking why didn't I get this idea? Maybe I was too tired of trying. Basically I'm really new to DJango. But thank you very much. I appreciate it!!